# How to calculate the average number of orders, taking into account the days when the product was in stock?

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables.

**Order** - contains information about orders.

```
+-----------+------------+
| ProductId |    Date    |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | 20.11.2021 |
|         2 | 20.11.2021 |
|         1 | 21.11.2021 |
|         1 | 21.11.2021 |
+-----------+------------+
```

**ProductQuantity** - contains information about the availability of goods in stock. The information is collected several times a day.

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+
| ProductId | Qunatity |     DateTime     |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
|         1 |       10 | 20.11.2021 09:00 |
|         1 |        5 | 20.11.2021 23:00 |
|         2 |        0 | 21.11.2021 09:00 |
|         2 |        0 | 21.11.2021 23:00 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+
```

I want to calculate the average number of orders per day for the last 5 days for a certain product. To do this, I make the following request. Then I divide the result by 5.

```sql
SELECT SUM(dayOrdersCount) AS totalCount
FROM
  (SELECT count(*) AS dayOrdersCount
   FROM
   ORDER o
   WHERE o.productId = 2
   GROUP BY o.date,
            o.productId
   ORDER BY o.date DESC
   LIMIT 5) a
```

In the example above, there may be a situation when there were no orders on some day (although the product was in stock) and the request will not take this data.

I tried to use `LEFT JOIN`, but in this case the total amount of stock availability was multiplied by the number of orders.

```sql
SELECT o.date,
         count(*) AS ordersQuantity,
         SUM(p.quantity) AS dayQuantity
FROM `Order` o
LEFT JOIN ProductQuantity AS p
    ON p.productId = o.productId
WHERE o.productId = 2
GROUP BY  o.date, o.productId, p.productId, p.date
ORDER BY  o.date DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

How is it possible to calculate the average number of orders for the last 5 days without taking into account the days when the goods were out of stock (for the whole day 0 in total)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 0):

Only ask for the last 5 days, then aggregate it again.

```
SELECT productId
, MIN(q.date) AS minDate
, MAX(q.date) AS maxDate 
, AVG(totalOrders) AS averageOrders
, AVG(productQuantity) AS averageProductQuantity
FROM
(
    SELECT o.productId, o.date
    , COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderId) AS totalOrders
    , SUM(p.quantity) AS productQuantity
    FROM `Order` AS o
    LEFT JOIN ProductQuantity AS p
      ON p.productId = o.productId
    WHERE o.productId = 2
      AND o.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
                     AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY o.productId, o.date
) q
GROUP BY productId
```